# Using promise to make multiple asynchronous calls, where only few are really important

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have to make few api calls to fetch data to generate a view. Lets say there are two api calls to be made, API1 and API2. API1 must get resolved in order to generate minimum view. If API2 also get resolved I can display extra feature.
I want to make both calls simultaneously and wait for API1 and API2 to resolve or reject using

```
promise.all([getAPI1, getAPI2]).then(/*both successs*/).catch(/*any one fails*/)
```

But as you can see, I have only two scenario covered here and not the one that I want. I have to resolve it even if API2 fails. How to do that??

Comment: One possible approach is wrapping API2 into another Promise that gets resolved anyway regardless of the actual result - but if it was a rejection, the result is some specific value. In this case, you can still use `.all`, just apply some check within `then` callback.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
Promise.all([
  fetchSomething(),
  fetchSomethingElse().catch(error => {
    // fetchSomethingElse failed (it's ok)
    return null;
  })
]).then(results => {
  // results[1] will be null when fetchSomethingElse fails
}).catch(error => {
  // fetchSomething failed
});
```

Comment: if fetchSomethingElse() fails, it will go into catch block??

Comment: Yes, if `fetchSomethingElse` returns a `Promise`

Comment: It does. Both fetchSomething and fetchSomethingElse return promise.

Comment: If so, you can call `fetchSomethingElse().catch(...)`. It will return a new `Promise` that will resolve with the fetched data or `null`.

Comment: Lost you completely. I can't understand you.

Comment: A 'Promise` object has the `catch` method, so if `fetchSomethingElse()` returns a `Promise`, you can call `fetchSomethingElse().catch(...)`, right? The `catch` method returns a new `Promise` (see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) for details). That new `Promise` will resolve with the fetched data or `null` if `fetchSomethingElse` fails. Does it make sense?

Comment: To chime in, even `.catch()` continues down the promise chain. By putting an "inner catch" on `fetchSomethingElse()`, that promise will resolve as the successful response (skipping the `.catch()` because it worked), or resolve as `null` (because the error was caught). But either way it will resolve and you can check its response in the outer `.then`

Comment: The problem is, if any of the request fails, I only get the error in catch block not the success of other response.